# 配送国の見分け方

Tags: paypal

購入された方が国内の方か海外の方かを見分ける方法として、

・DoExpressCheckoutPayment
・CreateRecurringPaymentProfile
・IPN通知

これらのどのパラメータ、変数を判断すればわかるでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

DoExpressCheckoutPaymentもしくはCreateRecurringPaymentProfileに対応するIPN通知内にある、
「residence_country」フィールドの値が""JP""の場合は国内、それ以外は海外(USやUKなど)になります。